# Ensure element remains in-view for at least a second

Tags: vue.js

i'm currently coding an infinite scroll search using ElasticSearch. However i'm having issues with detecting the bottom of the search area.

I have got the correct logic in-place, but due to delay's in the DOM updating, the code thinks the bottom is in view after the first initial search.

Hard to show the code due to it being spread across components, but this is the general logic:

```html
<div class="search-area">
    <div id="ajax-in-results">
        <!-- Results in here -->
    </div>
    <i id="this-is-the-bottom"></i>
</div>


<script>
    new IntersectionObserver(() => {
        /**
         * Some checks here specific to my other code, just stops it
         * sending too many requests etc... 
         */
        if (this.lastRequestId !== this.requestId && this.initialized) {
            /**
             * This emit will increase the current page number, and get more results
             */
            window.EventBus.$emit('search-set-page', this.current + 1)
            this.lastRequestId = this.requestId
        }
    }, {
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 1.0
    }).observe(document.querySelector('#this-is-the-bottom'));
</script>
```

As you can see below, the first 3 requests are fine, as there are initial requests for vehicles and settings. But during this time that `i` is visible, hence the second request ID. What is the best way to stopping the request from the `i` being visible for milliseconds.

I don't want to be defining a height... I feel the best way is to check this is within the viewport for at least 1 second, as currently it is only within view for like 1ms as I don't see it!

[image]

Comment: did you try using a watch or computed property?

Comment: On what?... lol

Comment: you got to store the results in some variable and gonna iterate it on the DOM right?

Comment: Yeah I store the results and I could watch this value however this doesn't answer my question in the slightest. Please read the question again

Comment: you don't want the <I> to be visible when each of the request ID set are loaded

Comment: I have updated the question as I guess it wasn't making sense. When I say visible I mean for the `IntersectionObserver`, not for me personally... but there will be data within the results from the first 3 requests